# Checking two graphs to be homeomorphic

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

How can I check that two simple connected graphs are homeomorphic? I know the [defenition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)) of homeomorfism, but I can't figure out when to stop subdividing, algoritmically. I need here some stopping inequality.

I've made a hypothesis:
$$ G_1 ~ is ~ homeomorphic ~ to ~ G_2 \Leftrightarrow \forall k \in \mathbb N \backslash \{2\} ~~ D_{G_1}^k = D_{G_2}^k $$
where $G_1, G_2$ both simple connected graphs and $D_{G}^k$ is number of vertices of degree $k$ in graph $G$.

But I can neither proof it from right to left<strike>, nor make a counter-example</strike>.

UPD: The counter-example had been given, but the suggestions on how to stop subdividing still needed. Alternative approaches would be appreciated, too.

UPD2: I have now a chain of necessary conditions:

if $G_1$ is homeomorphic to $G_2$ then

$
\bullet ~ \forall k \in \mathbb N \backslash \{2\} ~~ D_{G_1}^k = D_{G_2}^k 
$

$
\bullet ~ |E_1|-|V_1| = |E_2| - |V_2| 
$

$\bullet$ graphs $G_1'$ and $G_2'$ obtained by [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic.

UPD3: I've built implementation of homeomorphism searching in Scala. You can freely get it (and contribute to it!) at [github](https://github.com/FOODzee/Homeomorphism-searching). It's quite dummy, but I wouldn't develop it much futher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not true. I'm working on finding a counter-example for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is not true. A counter-example would be $K_{3,3}$ and the graph given by the following edgeset:
$$
(1,2)\; (1,3)\; (1,4)\; (2,3)\; (2,5)\; (3,6)\; (4,5)\; (4,6)\; (5,6)
$$
Both of these graphs have $6$ vertices each with degree $3$, but they are not homeomorphic.

It is true, though that 
$$
G_1 \;\mathrm{homeomorphic\ to}\; G_2 
  \;\implies\; 
(\forall k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{2\})\;\; D^k_{G_1} =  D^k_{G_2}
$$

so that should be the first check in your algorithm. I believe that instead of trying to find a common subdivision between two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ (by adding degree-$2$ vertices on existing edges), it may be easier to go in the other direction and remove all degree-$2$ vertices (*undo* all the possible subdivisions in $G_1$ and $G_2$). I believe that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic, then the resulting graphs of un-subdividing all possible edges in those graphs will be isomorphic. Algorithms on checking if two graphs are isomorphic, though potentially complicated, are much more documented then graph homeomorphism algorithms (there is a [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) dedicated to the problem of checking if two graphs are isomorphic).

Comment: Well, why aren't they? This litle thing, I suppose, is the only one to close my question, and the answer like 'obvious' or something like that wouldn't be very helpfull =)

Comment: There are two points in suggested algorithm (of removing degree-2 vertices): first, it is also left-to-right thing, so I'm not very sure that there is no counter-example like the one you give. Second, this 'I believe' thing isn't sounds good. And moreover, you haven't answered why do you think that your counter-example is really 'counter'.

Comment: The two graphs that I give are not homeomorphic because $K_{3,3}$ has no $3$-cycles while the graph that I gave the edgeset for has two $3$-cycles. Therefore the fact that two graphs have the same number of vertices with the same degree does not imply they are homeomorphic (i.e. right-to-left is not true).